# Using R to plot a set of numbers

Tags: r, plot, statistics

I have a set of numbers:

```
170,295,200,165,140,190,195,142,138,148,110,140,103,176,125,126,204,196,98,123,124
152,177,168,175,186,140,147,174,155,195
```

And I would like to use R to plot them in a histogram. Do I need to put them all in an array or something? I tried `X = a[170,...]` but that didn't work.

Comment: No need. Try `hist(x)` and `help(hist)` for help.

Comment: I would like to point out that a web search would have answered this in less time than it took to post this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should suffice

```
x <- c(170,295,200,165,140,190,195,142,138,148,110,140,103,
       176,125,126,204,196,98,123,124,152,177,168,175,186,140,
       147,174,155,195) 

hist(x)
```

[image]

Note that I used `c()` function to concatenate all numbers in one vector, and then I simply used `hist()` function to generate the histogram

Comment: Thanks for the explanation -- I didn't know you needed to use a vector to store the numbers. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MaxMackie You're welcome, feel free to accept the answer as correct if it meets your needs by cliking in the green tick mark :D

Comment: I definitely will, I just have to wait 5 minutes before I'm allowed to :)

Answer (score 2):

You want to combine or concatenate the individual elements (numbers) into a vector. Do this using the `c()` function. E.g.

```
dat <- c(170,295,200,165,140,190,195,142,138,148,110,140,103,176,125,126,204,
         196,98,123,124,152,177,168,175,186,140,147,174,155,195)
hist(dat)
```

produces

[image]